# How to increase the MDCTextField border width and make the corners more rounded?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, material-design, floating

I followed the https://material.io/design/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-single-line-text-field and have made the `MDCTextField` with `MDCTextInputControllerOutlined` controller and it works fine as shown in image.

Now I need to increase the width of the border and also make the corner more rounded.

I found this issue as listed below:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/issues/4173

It says :

> " That is the current behavior of OutlinedTextFields. It will automatically set the lineWidth to 2.0 while editing. you can find this in updateBorder implementation in MDCTextInputControllerOutlined."

So if we use `MDCTextInputControllerOutlined` can't we change the width of our textfield border?

Here is the code

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtFieldUserName: MDCTextField!
var userNameTextFieldController: MDCTextInputControllerOutlined?

userNameTextFieldController = MDCTextInputControllerOutlined(textInput: txtFieldUserName)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this class MDCTextField to MMTextField
https://gist.github.com/macchamps/8af7a8f8dc567ec16ad785b303bd90f6